# Issue with Parse.com database

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am having an issue adding a user to my User class in the parse database. I do not see any results after i launch the app and restart my parse.com webpage. Can someone assist me?

```
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(layout.activity_login);
  final   EditText username = (EditText) this.findViewById(id.userloginname);
    final EditText password = (EditText) this.findViewById(id.userpassword);


    TextView neighbourView = new TextView(this);

    Button button_test;
    button_test = (Button) this.findViewById(id.btnLogin);

    button_test.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {

          final  String usersname =  username.getText().toString();
          final  String passwoord = password.getText().toString();


            //ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Parking");
            ParseUser.logInInBackground(usersname, passwoord, new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, com.parse.ParseException e) {

                    if (user != null) {
                        // Hooray! The user is logged in.

                    } else {
                        //
                    }
                }



            });
            // return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a completely new user you should use `ParseUser.signUpInBackground()`:

```
ParseUser user = new ParseUser();
user.setUsername(username);
user.setPassword(password);
user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        //if e != null, something went wrong
    }
});
```

Comment: If you have already signed up with your user before and want to login, your code is OK. If the user has signed up before, you will find its row on parse.com . Logging in a registered user doesn't add new rows on the database.

Comment: Okay so how to i check to see if the user i am logging in with, is actually in the database?

Comment: Probably the most common approach is to have two buttons, *Log in* (logInInBackground()) and *Sign up* (signUpInBackground()).

Comment: i do have a login button but for some reason i cannot get it to be clickable.